# In memory queries using SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, common-table-expression

I'm afraid that even though I am using CTE's in my query, that maybe, behind the scenes, a lot of disk caching is going on -- so it may as well not be using CTE's.

The whole point of using CTE's was that my original query code was way too slow, and would eventually get a transport level error and crash.

Well, it's still too slow. Maybe even slower. I don't know yet.

Is there a way to tell SQL Server to go ahead and be resource hog for my query?

I am only guessing, but I think it is using disk space to cache memory results.  When I look at task manager memory utilization, I see SSMS at 161 MB. SSMS is where I am running the query from.

Here is my code - you don't have to read it in detail, but in brief, the source table contains about a million rows.

I need a solution, so alternative ideas are welcome...

```sql
    WITH MetEdFliers AS 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT
            [CustomerName1], [Mailing_Address], [Mailing_Address2], [Mailing_Zip]
        FROM 
            [dbo].[_MetEd_Detail]
        WHERE
            RunId = (SELECT RunId FROM LastLoadRuns WHERE UtilityId = 9)
            AND [Profitable] = 1   -- and not low income, should flag exist
    ),
    MetEdLookUpFirst AS 
    (
        -- same as [dbo].[VW_MetEd_Master_Profitable_ExcludeBadAddress]
       SELECT
           IIF (DET.IncalculableMailAddress = 1, 
                IIF (AA.Address1 IS NULL, 'Bad Address Undefined Fix -- Source Address Provided', 'Fixed Bad Source Address Via Lookup'), '') AS AddressStatus,
           DET.ACCT_NO,
           (CAST(DET.Monthly1 as Decimal) + 
            CAST(DET.Monthly2 as Decimal) + 
            CAST(DET.Monthly3 as Decimal) + 
            CAST(DET.Monthly4 as Decimal) + 
            CAST(DET.Monthly5 as Decimal) + 
            CAST(DET.Monthly6 as Decimal) + 
            CAST(DET.Monthly7 as Decimal) + 
            CAST(DET.Monthly8 as Decimal) + 
            CAST(DET.Monthly9 as Decimal) + 
            CAST(DET.Monthly10 as Decimal) + 
            CAST(DET.Monthly11 as Decimal) + 
            CAST(DET.Monthly12 as Decimal)) AS BilledKWHTotal,
           DET.Polar, DET.CustomerName1, 
           REPLACE (IIF (DET.IncalculableMailAddress = 1,
                         IIF (AA.Address1 IS NULL, DET.Mailing_Address, AA.Address1), DET.Mailing_Address), ',', ';') AS Address1,
           REPLACE (IIF (DET.IncalculableMailAddress = 1,
                         IIF (AA.Address2 IS NULL, DET.Mailing_Address2,  AA.Address2), DET.Mailing_Address2), ',', ';') AS Address2,
           REPLACE (IIF (DET.IncalculableMailAddress = 1,
                         IIF (AA.City IS NULL, DET.Mailing_City, AA.City), DET.Mailing_City), ',', ';') AS City,
           IIF (DET.IncalculableMailAddress = 1,
                IIF (AA.[State] IS NULL, DET.Mailing_State, AA.[State]), DET.Mailing_State) AS [State],
           IIF (DET.IncalculableMailAddress = 1, 
                IIF (AA.Zip IS NULL, DET.Mailing_Zip, AA.Zip), DET.Mailing_Zip) AS ZIP,
           IIF (DET.IncalculableMailAddress = 1, '', DET.Mailing_Zip4) AS ZIP4,
           REPLACE (DET.Address, ',', ';') AS ServiceAddress,
           REPLACE (DET.City, ',', ';') AS ServiceAddressCity,
           DET.State ASs ServiceAddressState,
           DET.Zip AS ServiceAddressZip,
           DET.Zip4 AS ServiceAddressZip4,
           DET.ProfitAnnualPotential AS [Potential Annual Profit]
       FROM
           _MetEd_DETAIL DET 
       LEFT JOIN
           AccountAddress AA ON (DET.ACCT_NO = AA.ACCT_NO AND AA.UtilityId = 9)
       WHERE
           RunId = (SELECT RunId FROM LastLoadRuns WHERE UtilityId = 9)
           AND DET.Profitable = 1 --AND det.CAP_CUSTOMER = 0
           AND (DET.IncalculableMailAddress = 0 OR (AA.Address1 IS NOT NULL))
    )
    SELECT X.* 
    FROM MetEdFliers Fliers
    OUTER APPLY 
        (SELECT TOP 1 *
         FROM MetEdLookUpFirst LU
         WHERE LU.CustomerName1 = Fliers.CustomerName1 
           AND LU.Address1 = Fliers.Mailing_Address 
           AND LU.Address2 = Fliers.Mailing_Address2 
           AND LU.Zip = Fliers.Mailing_Zip) X
```

Comment: CTEs are not (in general) going to change the performance of the query in SQL Server.  At all.

Comment: In my daily business,I learned that temp tables perform much better in case of performance. So try to write your CTEs into temp tables (like `SELECT ... INTO #T1 FROM ...`)

Comment: It seems the query is returning 1M relatively wide rows and you're displaying in SSMS. I suspect it's the client not the server. Try running the query with the SSMS discard result sets option to see how long it takes.

Comment: or try `OPTION (FORCE ORDER)` in the last line

Comment: You need to post your execution plan and STATISTICS IO output

Comment: What is the purpose of this? To create a data dump for something else? Note that there is no `ORDER BY` in your `OUTER APPLY` query so you are doing all that work and not getting a determined `TOP 1` record, just a random one. I also see distincts and nested selects in a where clause so there are a lot of indicators here that this might be able to be rewritten to run faster, but you need a good understanding of cardinality between tables.

Comment: This is an on-the -fly data cleansing exercise. If you have the opportuntiy you should pre-cleanse the data and add an indicator to the `_MetEd_DETAIL ` table then probably create a filtered index on that

Comment: SMMS? Do you mean SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)? The query is actually executed by the database engine in a separate process, e.g. `sqlservr.exe`.

Comment: yep.  ssms     .  comments must be at least 15 chars long

Answer (score 0):

It looks to be difficult.
I am going to handle it in my source program that generates input files for the sql server database ( i real the cvs into a table using import ).

To handle this problem, I am going to use a technology called dictionary, with key value pair, in c#.

I will be able to tell if the key had been added before, and if so, I replace the key value pair with the new key value pair and the annual profit potential field with the sum from both records....

Note:  Prior method, I did not have sum (enhancement).

Comment: How is that going to cleanse your data? Most of your query is trying to clean data on the fly and pick a single address.